# how can i implement password.confirm middleware in multi gurds ( auth:web, auth:admin )?

Tags: laravel

Routes of Web are in `routes/web.php` and
Routes of Admin are in `routes/Admin.php`

if I add `(->middleware(password.confirm))` in any of the `web.php` Routes => it works done, and
if I add `(->middleware(password.confirm))` in any of the `Admin.php` Routes => it works done, but

if I add in both just a `admin.php` Routes works correctly,  and in web.php routes, the middleware automatically redirect back

Comment: what does your middleware? i suppose, you can hadle your task by validated request. show us a bit of code or explain more

Comment: my middleware is password.confirm .... if I'm user or admin in application  and i visit any links(route) inside app . this middleware redirect me to a page for asking me to confirm my password for visiting this links

Comment: i suppose no one can help you without code. show your middleware and routes

Comment: can i use attempt method after login ??